# Is there a way to run a script on IPython interactively so that it comes afterwards what is already written?

Tags: python, ipython, interactive

Is there a way to run a script in iPyton with the `%run myscript.py` so that it will  take into consideration the things I have already entered in the interactive iPython console?

Example:

```
In [1]: asdf = 18

In [2]:
```

Then if myscript.py was:

```
print asdf
```

And it was ran from iPython like this:

```
In [2]: %run myscript.py
18

In [3]:
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`%load`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.2/interactive/qtconsole.html#load) magic function, available in the IPython Notebook (qtconsole or web version). It allows you to load the contents of a file into a cell, edit them if you want, then run them in the current context.

Comment: Thanks for aswering so quickly~

Answer (score 0):

Use %logstart/%logon and %logstop/%logoff. With these controls, you will have a python_log.py file that stores your history.